# Not generating the same random number multiple times in a loop

Tags: java, loops, random

I'm new to Java so apologies in advance if any of this is unclear (or the code is really bad), but I am trying to build a program that gets the computer to guess a two digit code that the user has entered (i.e. `secretCode`). The following piece of code works fine and it will generate a random code that is then compared to the secret code and check if there are positions entered in the correct place.

However, how would I do it so that each time the computer guessed, it wouldn't be able to guess a number it has previously guessed (e.g. if it guesses 57 on the first guess, it can't pick 57 again for the duration of the loop). Basically I want the computer to keep track of the guesses it has made and not do them again. Any ideas how this is possible (without substantial rewriting of the program if possible)? Or am I going the wrong way about this?

```
while (guesses < 10)
      int[] compCode = computer.getComputerCode(); //This line gets a random two digit array of ints
      System.out.print("Computer guess: ");
      Arrays.stream(compCode).forEach(System.out::print);
      correctPositions = getPosition(compCode, secretCode);

      System.out.println("\nYou picked " + correctPositions + " numbers in the correct position.");
      guesses++;
}
```

Comment: How about you generate a list of all numbers in the appropriate range, shuffle it, and then iterate through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is populate an `ArrayList` with numbers and then shuffle the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
  guesses.add(i);
}
//guesses now contains numbers 0-99
Collections.shuffle(guesses);
```

And then whenever you need a random number you can simply call an index of `guesses` (Make sure you keep track of what index you're on)

An example could be something like:

```
while(some_condition) {
   //start count at -1, so when we add one it will be 0
   //which is the first index of the ArrayList
   int count = -1;
   //Some code
   guesses.get(count++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the list approach is good. The only issue I have now is how I use that within the while loop so that each time it iterates through it gets a different a different number - i.e. using .get() to call an index of guesses so that the first time through it calls .get(0), second time .get(1) etc. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @Logan I edited in an example to show you how you can do this

Answer (score -1):

I think GBlodgett has the right idea, but another way would be to store guesses in a list and put

```
if(guesses.contains(guess)
   continue;
```

in the first lines of the while loop

Comment: Using a list for this would make the algorithm run in quadratic time. I would prefer a HashSet for storing previous guesses.